# error in upgrading angular 1.2.12 to 1.3.15

Tags: angularjs, url, upgrade

All things are working fine except url that

With angular 1.2.12 if i open url  `127.0.0.1:8080/#` then it will remove '#' after trailing slash and new url will be `127.0.0.1:8080/` .

With angular 1.3.15 if i open url  `127.0.0.1:8080/#` then it does not change .

I used html5mode to remove hashtags

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
  });
```

Other then that what can be the breaking change?

Comment: does it affect the routing behavior?

Comment: No, it does'nt affect.

Comment: so it's just bothers you to see the `#` on the `/` route. check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629774/i-am-trying-to-remove-the-hashtag-from-the-angularjs-ng-route

Comment: Facebook login api leaves  #_=_  behind so it it necessary for me to clean url. Even after doing  window.location.hash = ' ' this '#' is not removing. Its just happening only due to change in angular version (rest of the code is same)

Answer (score 0):

Uses otherwise at end of your routes:

.otherwise({redirectTo : '/'})