# How to keep base href in location?

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I want to implement an AngularJS based admin backend on my website.

Say the backend is located at `/admin` and I've set my `<base href="/admin">` and I set my routing up like the following

```
angular
    .module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
    .controller('MainController', function ($scope) {})
    .controller('DashboardController', function ($scope) {});
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/dashboard', {
                    templateUrl: '/admin/static/app/dashboard/dashboard.html',
                    controller: 'DashboardController'
                });
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        }]);
```

and my navigation looks like

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
</div>
```

Now I'm at `/admin/` and click on `Dashboard` it will set my window location to `/dashboard` instead of `/admin/dashboard` - this is what I mean by it leaves the `base href`.

Is there a way to keep the `base href` in the location?

Comment: What is `...` in a relative url?

Comment: @toddmo does the `templateUrl` really matter for the question tho? Updated the question

Comment: No it doesn't but I was like, cool, new syntax what does it do? lol

Comment: How come you don't just say `<li><a href="/admin/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>`?

Comment: @toddmo Because because I'd have to do it through my complete routing (`.when('/admin/...) etc`) and I don't want to care about the path where my app is located. Just set it once at root level and fine.

Comment: I had a struggle with the same basic thing. Here's what happened, in case it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726289/how-to-get-html5mode-application-to-be-root-relative-instead-of-server-root-rela

Answer (score 0):

you should try to do this

```
<a href="#/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
```

the # makes it relative and the registered routes support this out of the box.
by the way normally you don't use href's in angularjs. you rather put some ng-click element and use the $location service with $location.path('dashboard')

Comment: But I don't want to use hashes, thus I've set the HTML5 mode with `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`?