# Unwanted hash '#' in url, using $routeProvider in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route-provider

When I'm starting my application the following url is opened: `http://localhost:8080/#/`. What I'm trying to do is to open this url: `http://localhost:8080/` when the application is loaded, but I'm not able to achieve this.

I'm using AngularJS and `$routeProvider` to load content based on url. I'm quite not sure how it works and documentation is not clear to me. This is the code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('login', ['login.filters', 'login.services', 'login.directives', 'login.controllers']).
    config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', controller: 'MyCtrl1'});
        $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    }]);
```

Can you help me spot unwanted '#' ?

Comment: The hash is fundamental to angular routing unless running in html mode and there are significant caveats to consider before doing so.  Spend some time reading the documentation on the router.

Comment: Read the manual...it's all explained there

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

This describes how to achieve what you want, as well as educating you on what the # is for and how Angular utilizes it

Comment: While links to sources of information are good, the relevant information should be quoted here and should show an example of how to use said information.

Answer (score 0):

Angular will load pages dynamically and stores/reads the current page from in the url after the `#` symbol.

You could try enabled html5 mode for location
[How to remove the hash # from the angularjs ng-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629774/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-the-angularjs-ng-route)