# #%2F is getting added in Angular routing and not working in angular 1.6.4

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to set the routes in my first single page application from 2 days,I dont know what is happening with the application.When i click any of the link,like say i clicked the login link then http://localhost:3000/#!/#%2Flogin this is what gets in the requested url and when i did some experiments to see then i found that http://localhost:3000/#!/login shows me the login template. How to correct it.
My code
Html>>

```
<a href="/#/">Posts</a>
<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/#/register">Register</a>
<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/#/login">Login</a>
```

route.js>>

```
angular.module('app')
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/',{controller:'PostsCtrl',templateUrl:'posts.html'})
.when('/register',{controller:'RegisterCtrl',templateUrl:'register.html'})
.when('/login',{controller:'LoginCtrl',templateUrl:'login.html'})
});
```

Comment: add the `!` in the href

Comment: can you describe

Comment: in your html `<a href="/#!/">Posts</a>`
`<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/#!/register">Register</a>`
`<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/#!/login">Login</a>` i added `!`

Comment: yes it routed me to the login.html now...but can you tell me why the link shows http://localhost:3000/#!/login this #!

Comment: thats because by default routing does, even if you use ng-routes or  ui-routes, if you want to avoid now the answers provided below can help you @Athanasios  proviede one with base and html5 modeon, and @Sajeetharan provides a way to don use the `!`

Comment: i tried implemeting the steps they told me to do but i am still not getting the desired result.do i have to change my href when i use their methods?

Comment: what method do you want to use ? ... with base or without `!`

Comment: without !...i changed my config file...tell me do i need to have another ng-script for locationProvider ???

Answer (score 0):

First off, You can remove the hash entirely by enabling html5 mode. Add this to your configuration:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
```

This post might help: [How to remove the hash # from the angularjs ng-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629774/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-the-angularjs-ng-route)

Secondly, you don't need to reference the hash when you are linking to another template. I usually use this simple go function to redirect pages in my angular app. Then simply call the template you want to load by calling go('./template_name'). Also, you should use ng-click instead of href.

```
vm.go = function(_path) {
    $location.path(_path);
}
```

Comment: that doesnt solve the `!` issue, you propouse another way to handle routing. not solving the issue.

Comment: @JesusCarrasco enabling html5 mode removes both # and !.  http://localhost:3000/#!/login would become  http://localhost:3000/login

Comment: thats correct but he is asking why the `!` appears and who solving the ! wihtout change his href. you propose its correct if he want to use base, reference. i just say it doesnt solve the ! problem he has.

Comment: i tried writing your code @AthanasiosBabasidis but when i did gulp dev to it..their comes an error throw er ...|| error: couldn't process source due to parse error

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your config to avoid the `!`

```
angular.module('app')
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{controller:'PostsCtrl',templateUrl:'posts.html'})
    .when('/register',{controller:'RegisterCtrl',templateUrl:'register.html'})
    .when('/login',{controller:'LoginCtrl',templateUrl:'login.html'})
});
```

And in the HTML keep like you have before. without `!`

Comment: i think i was not doing gulp dev to the code and so it was not concatinating i got the problem solved that why their added codes dint worked till now.But now the problem is adding their code and doing gulp gives me parse error..

Comment: well you have the options. if want keep the ! just add to every href, if whant base use the Athanasios, or if whant not include ! use mine or Sajeerathan.  if on the deployment the gulp give error, try asking in other question. Glad to help.

Comment: i can only post once in every 90 mins.do you mind @Jesus Carrasco if you could help me here