# AngularJS $routeProvider doesn't route properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5mode

So I'm new to Angular and trying to figure out how multiple routes can lead to the same view/templateUrl and controller. Here is what I've written:

```
angular
  .module('mwsApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.bootstrap'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    // debugger
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl as vm',
      })
      .when('/rika', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl as vm',
      })
      // .otherwise({
      //   redirectTo: '/'
      // });

      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix("!");
  });
```

Issue: Currently, if I go to "localhost:9000/" it shows me the correct version, but if I go to "localhost:9000/rika" it gives me "Cannot get /rika".

Debugging: I've narrowed down the problem to html5Mode. I'm trying to get rid of the #! that Angular adds automatically onto the URL, but when I do that, the error pops up.

Appreciate anyone's input!

Comment: You cannot get rid of the address hashing, that defeats the purpose of routing with Angular (also AJAX'ing) etc...

Comment: Yes you can, I haven't fiddled around with it personally but it is possible

Comment: Take a look at [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629774/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-the-angularjs-ng-route)

Comment: I guess one learns something new every day. It just seems like a lot of hassle for what benefit?

Comment: You can use `$stateProvider` to solve this thing

Answer (score 1):

You cant get rid of `#` in `local development` so you need to comment this line

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix("!");
```

But when you're on some `server on production` then `uncomment` and use it to remove the `#`

otherwise you'll keep getting not get error on `reloads in local development`

Comment: This still doesn't work on production, site.com/rika still causes problems

Comment: add base tag in your html and just doing this wont help, you need to do some setting on your server, based on what are you using like nginx, s3 etc