# Angular PathLocationStrategy issue in s3 bucket

Tags: angular, serverless, serverless-architecture, s3-bucket

On PathLocationStrategy when i'm reload page then getting 404 page not found. and I don't want to use HashLocationStrategy.

Comment: Please add additional information about your issue.

Comment: ex.www.example.com/page1 so when I'm reloading then getting 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

Copy there `redirection rule` under `static web hosting` in `s3`

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <Protocol>http</Protocol>
      <HostName>Copy Endpoint Link under static web hosting</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>#/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Check this answer of mine, you need to make some changes in angular code too

[AngularJS $routeProvider doesn't route properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46071669/angularjs-routeprovider-doesnt-route-properly/46071817#46071817)